# ARM64 llvm unrecognized instruction mnemonic

Tags: android, llvm, arm64

I am trying to use ARM inline assembly in a C code. I am compiling using aarch64-linux-android-clang version 3.8.243773, the 64 bit llvm toolchain from Android NDK R11.

The inline assembly code is as follows:

```
__asm__("ssat %w0, #24, %w1\n\t"
      : "=r" (val)
      : "r" (val)
      : );
```

I am looking to saturate a 32 bit result to 24 bits using this inline assembly.

The syntax of inline assembly code is correct and it compiles the syntax code as such but the assembler spits out a error saying

error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic ssat

What is the problem here? Doesn't llvm from the ndk toolchain support this assembly instruction?

How can I  fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: If you want to build AArch64 code, it would help to use AArch64 instructions...

Comment: When i looked up in ARM document ARM DUI0802A which is armasm reference guide for arm compiler, for AArch64, the instruction to saturate is still shown as SSAT.  But i am not using arm compiler.  As i said, its aarch64-linux-android-clang. Do you know if there is any different saturation instruction for aarch64?

Comment: The armasm documentation covers all three instruction sets because armasm supports both AArch32 and AArch64 code, as does LLVM (whereas with the GNU toolchain they're completely different backends/builds). That still doesn't mean you can mix and match A32 and A64 instructions _within_ the same piece of code, because that's just not how the architecture works. AFAICS there's no scalar saturating arithmetic in A64, so it's probably a case of doing it with NEON if you're processing enough data to make that worthwhile, or just doing it in C code otherwise.

Comment: Ok. I don't want to do this small macro for saturation in NEON as i suspect the overhead of load store from ARM to NEON and back will negate the benefits if any.  I have tried using a many of the instructions using inline assembly, and they work fine with llvm aarch64, its just this ssat which is not supported. A quick search tells me llvm does have some issue for this mnemonic : http://reviews.llvm.org/D6976

Comment: In the ARMv8 Arch Reference doc, the SSAT instructions are only available as T32 and A32 instructions, not in 64bit mode.